# Convert pose data into twist message

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, amcl-pose

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working through a tutorial in which I have a series of pose positions for a robot saved to a file. Example below:

```
rostopic echo /amcl_pose
header:
  seq: 0
  stamp:
    secs: 2846
    nsecs: 567000000
  frame_id: "map"
pose:
  pose:
    position:
      x: -0.0395007291156
      y: -0.0213931718838
      z: 0.0
    orientation:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: -0.00131714215996
      w: 0.999999132568
  covariance: [0.20861109843009223, 0.003308687018433075, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.003308687018433077, 0.22561699161902968, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.05838497295545044]
---
```

I have multiple **pose.pose** data sections, containing the position and orientation, saved to a file.

I want to send my robot to each of my saved poses but how can I convert the position and orientation amcl_pose data into linear and angular geometry_msgs/Twist messages ?

**UPDATE: **

I am following [**Mastering with ROS: Summit XL - Set Indoor Navigation Stack**](https://www.theconstructsim.com/robotigniteacademy_learnros/ros-courses-library/mastering-ros-summit-xl/) on theConstructSim.

My code for sending my goal to the move_base is as follows:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import rospy
import actionlib
from move_base_msgs.msg import MoveBaseAction, MoveBaseGoal

class SummitNavigationClient() :

    def __init__(self) :
        rospy.loginfo('... navigation-client starting')

        move_base = actionlib.SimpleActionClient('move_base', MoveBaseAction)
        move_base.wait_for_server()
            
        goal = MoveBaseGoal()
        goal.target_pose.pose.position.x = -2.76009410711
        goal.target_pose.pose.position.y = -3.60989414856
        goal.target_pose.pose.position.z = 0.0
        goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.x = 0.0
        goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.y = 0.0
        goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.z = 0.000899836262279
        goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.w = 0.999999595147

        move_base.send_goal(goal)

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    rospy.init_node('my_summit_navigation_client')
    try :
        navigator = SummitNavigationClient()
        rospy.spin()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException as e :
        rospy.logerr('Something went wrong: %s', e)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/373025/convert-pose-data-into-twist-message/) by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 247 on 2021-03-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2021-03-01**:
Please, add a link to the tutorial you're following.

**Comment by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on 2021-03-02**:
I just realised there was a typo in my code the the point where I was executing `move_base.send_goal(...)`.
It is now corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is the job of navigation, or maybe a controller, depending on your application.  One option is to use `move_base` ([wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base)) and send each pose as a goal once your robot has achieved the previous pose.  Another option (ignoring obstacles and other complications) could be to implement a feedback controller that simply operates on the difference between the current pose and the desired pose, though that may be tricky depending on the robot's dynamics.  If you provide more information about your application and intent, we can find a more specific answer.

---

Originally posted by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) with karma: 1421 on 2021-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on 2021-03-01**:
I appreciate your input. My question is updated with my code.

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2021-03-02**:
Since you found the typo in your code, is your question satisfied?

**Comment by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on 2021-03-02**:
Actually, **no**. My robot still does not move when I send my goal to my move_base client.

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2021-03-02**:
I assume you would have posted any errors, so can you confirm if the goal is actually sent to the server by running `rostopic echo /move_base/goal` in a terminal and looking for the correct goal data?  Can you also confirm whether `move_base` is sending twist messages by echoing `cmd_vel`?

**Comment by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on 2021-03-02**:
No data is being published to **/move_base/goal**, **/move_base_simple/goal** nor **/summit_xl_control/cmd_vel**
I am not sure thie line is having any effect: **move_base = actionlib.SimpleActionClient('move_base', MoveBaseAction)**.
I replaced *move_base* with something obviously incorrect and the system did not complain. So, I am unsure how to discover the correct move_base node.
**UPDATE:**I just noticed and confirmed there is a **/move_base/goal** topic so it seems my code above is valid

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2021-03-02**:
Try filling out the header of the `goal` message, for example:

```
goal.target_pose.header.frame_id = "map"
goal.target_pose.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
```

**Comment by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on 2021-03-02**:
I have tried adding those lines as you suggested but my robot still did not move.
Just to make you aware of my steps, I start by executing `rosrun move_base move_base` and then I execute my python script containing my code in the original question.
In the move_base terminal, there is the following warning:

```
[ WARN] [1614737784.021718163, 266.005000000]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link tomap to become available before running costmap, tf error: canTransform: source_frame base_link does not exist.. canTransform returned after 0.1 timeout was 0.1.
[ WARN] [1614737789.044118992, 271.012000000]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link tomap to become available before running costmap, tf error: canTransform: source_frame base_link does not exist.. canTransform returned after 0.1 timeout was 0.1.
```

I'm not sure why or if it has some bearing on why my robot is still unresponsive.

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2021-03-03**:
Have you been able to get your robot to move without your script, i.e., by sending a direct `cmd_vel` message or `move_base` goal?

**Comment by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on 2021-03-03**:
I can issue a `cmd_vel` command and the robot does move. But for `move_base`, I am using my python script as detailed above to set a goal - which is what isn't working

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2021-03-03**:
The tutorial you linked has previous exercises for navigation with `move_base`.  Did you complete those sections?  `cmd_vel` works, so the next step is to make sure `move_base` functions with input from RViz or the command line before trying to use custom code.  Also, have you tried getting help from [The Construct Forum](https://get-help.robotigniteacademy.com/c/course-support/masteringwithrossummitxl/24)?  They are certainly more familiar with the tutorial than I am.

**Comment by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on 2021-03-03**:
You are quite correct but the tutorial I'm on did not require previously completing a move_base course. It's worth considering at this point.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It was a BIG oversight on my part.
It should have been obvious immediately I saw the `ros waiting for transform from base_link to map` warnings.

I failed to provide a map for the system to work with. I assumed a map was only needed when I am doing **GMapping** or **AMCL**.

So, the solution was to execute a launch file which has a map_server node with an argument leading to my map.yaml file.

The transform warning above was specifically resolved by creating an AMCL node which has a rosparam name of *global_frame_id* and value map i.e :

```
<param name="global_frame_id" value="map"/>
```

Executing my launch file, the move_base node and my python node with the code in my original question then successfully moved my robot to the presaved odometry point . . . when it didn't complain about "**Aborting because a valid control could not be found. Even after executing all recovery behaviors**"

Thanks @tryan.

---

Originally posted by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) with karma: 247 on 2021-03-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1